# Markov chains why the sum of the incoming probabilities is greater than 1?

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, statistical-mechanics

[image]

I have this Markov chain for a set of states, there are the outgoing and the incoming probabilities, it's an exercise, the teacher told us to check that the outgoing probabilities ($p_m^{out}=\sum_n p_{mn}$) for each state are correctly normalized, but he also asked us to calculate the sum of the incoming probabilities ($p^{in}$), and there are two elements for which the sum of the $p^{in}$'s is greater than 1 ($A_3$ and $A_4$), then the average $p^{in}$ (which he asked us to calculate as well) is also greater than 1, what does it mean? or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a given state can, in theory, be reached from multiple states, there is no reason for the incoming probabilities to sum to $\leq 1$.

Comment: @lulu so the average of the incoming probabilities is not the probability of a state to be reached for another one, or yes? what does it mean then?

Comment: $P(X_{n+1}=j)=\sum_i p_{ij} P(X_n=i)$, which is a *weighted* average of the $p_{ij}$, weighted against the distribution of $X_n$.

Comment: To take an extreme example, take whatever Process you are used to and adjoin $100$ states, each of which can not be reached from any other state and each of which go to the given state with probability $1$. Doesn't change anything about the probability of any state, but we just added $100$ to the sum of the incoming probabilities for the given state.